# MVC Linq query with both group by columns and Max table column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, max

I'm trying to create a query that gets me all unique records of 4 columns plus the Id column from the same table.

```
var newTSOnly = NewExport.GroupBy(g => new { g.TrainingAttended, g.TrainingLocation, g.Trainer, g.DateOfTrainingSession }).ToList();
```

The above gets me all the unique records I want but I can't find a way also get the "NewExports" "Id" field.

My aim is to create a record in a different table for each unique record but I require the Id field for other things afterwards.

I've tested it in a sql query and found it to work with adding MAX(Id) as an extra select value but still trying to get this to work in linq.

```
SELECT [TrainingAttended],[TrainLocation],[Trainer],[DateofTrain], MAX([Id]) As Id
FROM [TrainingExport].[dbo].[MasterRegisterExport]
GROUP BY [TrainingAttended],[TrainLocation],[Trainer],[DateofTrain]
```

I can't seem to find the linq equivalent if anybody can give me a pointer thanks?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the ID only as I understood then you should only add the new ID value:

```
var newTSOnly = NewExport.GroupBy(g => new { g.TrainingAttended, g.TrainingLocation, g.Trainer, g.DateOfTrainingSession, g.Id }).ToList();
```

Getting the max like in Sql should work like this:

```
var newTSOnly = NewExport.GroupBy(g => new { g.TrainingAttended, g.TrainingLocation, g.Trainer, g.DateOfTrainingSession, g.Max(x => x.Id) }).ToList();
```